# The Closed topologist's sin curve

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

1. If the topologist's sin curve is defined with $0 \times [-1,1]$ included then why is it called the closed topologist's sin curve when in the subspace topology the topologist's sin curve is closed? Every set is clopen in it's subspace topology.
2. Let's just think of discs around the origin of the topologist's sin curve $T$ without $0 \times [-1,1]$ for a second, if we could please, in comparison to the interval (0,1]; presumably there are sequences of points in T, which are intersections of closed discs with the topologist's sin curve constituting the closure of the neighborhood $A$ around the origin which is also such an intersection. Now again, any sequence in the closure can't converge to any point on X=1 which is not existant in this subspaces topology so how is that to disprove the local compactness property? (0,1] is similar. Is it just not compact \ bounded as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? It is the image of a compact set (0,1] anyways which I read is compact!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called closed because it's a closed subset of the plane. The extra limit points of $\{(x, \sin(\frac{1}{x})), x \in (0,1]\}$ are $\{0\} \times [-1,1]$; e.g. as these points occur as limits of sequences from the sine-graph part. So in total that space becomes connected (the graph is, and the closure of a connected set is connected). So it's certainly **not** true that every subset is clopen in the subspace topology, far from it.

The whole closed topologist's sine curve is compact (closed and bounded; Heine-Borel). This means that every point of it has compact neighbourhoods: the closed balls (in the subspace topology, so the Euclidean ones intersected with the subspace) are compact too. It has nothing to do with $(0,1]$ or sequences.

Comment: ${-1} \cup (0,1]$ is compact in the defn I read- it contains $(0,1]$ so hows (0,1] not compact then

Comment: @7einadh $\{-1\} \cup (0,1]$ is *locally compact* not compact. And your small topologist's sine-curve is a continuous image of it.

Comment: Every set ought to be "closed" in it's induced topology _if it's the intersection with a closed set-; so although the topologist's sine curve without it's limit points as a subset of "R2" isn't closed, it is closed in the induced topology right? I can not tell if it counts as an intersection with the closed topologist's sine curve. Thanks ----

Comment: @7einadh It's closed in itself, as any topological space. But the larger version is also closed (even compact) in the plane. The smaller version is not. The closedness in the name refers to its being closed as a subset of the plane.

Comment: Thank you for the help